# String to Bitmap java/android

Tags: java, android

I am developing an application in which I converted a bitmap to string for some purprose.
How can I convert that String  into a Bitmap again?

Comment: what kind of String? do you mean you want to render text into an image?

Comment: No, I converted an Bitmap to String to do some work, no I want to convert it back... it looks like "android.graphics.Bitmap@43fd34c0"

Answer (score 2):

> I converted an Bitmap to String to do some work, now I want to convert it back... it looks like "android.graphics.Bitmap@43fd34c0"

Simply stated, you can't.

That string is produced by the default `Object.toString()` method.  It does not encode the information content of the object, and there is nothing in the standard class libraries that will turn it back into a reference to the original object ... assuming that it still exists.

Your only hope is if you create a `Map<String,Bitmap>` and populate it with mappings; e.g.

```
Map<String, Bitmap> map = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
...
map.put(someBitmap.toString(), someBitmap);
...
Bitmap retrieved = map.get(someString);
```