# Convert Bitmap to String

Tags: android

Can I convert Bitmap to String?
And then convert the String back to the Bitmap?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041849/string-to-bitmap-java-android

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android code to convert base64 string to bitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801760/android-code-to-convert-base64-string-to-bitmap)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837110/how-to-convert-a-base64-string-into-a-bitmap-image-to-show-it-in-a-imageview

Comment: Have you tried search at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ea2c4fbb9729cd26) code appears to be what you want to convert to a string:

This shows how to do both:
[How to convert a Base64 string into a BitMap image to show it in a ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837110/how-to-convert-a-base64-string-into-a-bitmap-image-to-show-it-in-a-imageview)

And this one shows converting back to a .bmp:
[Android code to convert base64 string to bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801760/android-code-to-convert-base64-string-to-bitmap)

Google is your friend... you should always ask your friends if they know the answer first :)

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Any file format

```
public String photoEncode(File file){
        try{

            byte[] byteArray = null;

            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream =  new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)); 
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[1024*8];
            int bytesRead =0;

            while ((bytesRead = bufferedInputStream.read(b)) != -1)
            {
                bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            byteArray = bos.toByteArray();
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
            bos = null;

            return changeBytetoHexString(byteArray);

        }catch(Exception ex){           
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private String changeBytetoHexString(byte[] buf){


        char[] chars = new char[2 * buf.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; ++i)
        {
            chars[2 * i] = HEX_CHARS[(buf[i] & 0xF0) >>> 4];
            chars[2 * i + 1] = HEX_CHARS[buf[i] & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(chars);
    }
```