# How to Convert String of EditText into Bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-edittext

I wanted to convert string of EditText to Bitmap.
 have a string like this

```
String str=edtext.getText().toString();
```

How can i convert that string to bitmap?

Comment: This is same to convert iphone to android

Comment: then how can it be done in iphone

Comment: did you mean you want an image of what is there in the textbox ? for e.g. if there is "2" in textbox then you want image of "2" ?

Comment: my dear its not possible String is different data type then bitmap try to open any bitmap in text viewer and check if u r able to read the content

Comment: possible duplicate of [String to Bitmap java/android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041849/string-to-bitmap-java-android)

Comment: @arjun yeah i meant so..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bitmap from String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046240/bitmap-from-string)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I dont know about how to make image of that `string` but here is code to make `Bitmap` from and `EditText`

So you will get Bitmap image of the whole EditText not only String with this,

```
mEditText.setCursorVisible(false);
mEditText.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mEditText.getDrawingCache());
```

Comment: He could also create a Canvas and then use drawText method, although is not as easy as your way ;-)

Comment: @Ashish Bhai,You asked the question wrongly so you got weired comments,while asking always be precise to get exact answers.

Comment: @momo yeh! I suggest if you have code demo for that also put that as an answer so the all can have options to use..cause many like me don't know how to use canvas.

Comment: @ frank thanks for yuor comment..the code for me was to convert the edit text convert and then merge it as a single image , so as to use it for a photo captioning app. the image here is an image of a 'captioning'. i am putting the code as my answer

Comment: @Ashish I understand,So I have one more idea for you...make one full transparent image from designer,now when user submit caption..then first set that image to edittext and then convert it to bimap and then combine both bitmap caption and image so the white bg of edittext will not come..just and idea not implemented.

Comment: thnx frnk..i tried to post the answer. but stackovflw says i have to wait for 8 hours ..so iw uill post it tomorrow.. hope it helps you somewhere in ur prgmmg too..

Comment: @Frankenstein : hi frank, sorry for the delay.. i have added the answer ..hope it helps at some point..happy new year!!..

Comment: I am missing something, can't create bitmap, nullpointexception for myTextView.getDrawingCache() ?

Comment: this code is really helpful. I am assigning that image generated to a image view  but each time when I edit that text in Edittext I am not getting Updated Image.

Comment: @JogendraGouda You will need to created new image each time and set that to Imageview again, for that you can move that code to EditText's onTextChange method, take care of recycling the unused bitmap else you will run out of memory.

Comment: @MKJParekh Thank you for yr comment.
can you please show me some part of your code.

Comment: my code? which code you want to see? creating bitmap is up there, you also have done that in your app. @JogendraGouda

Comment: @MKJParekh 
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

et.setCursorVisible(false);

et.buildDrawingCache();

Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(et.getDrawingCache());

ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


img.setImageBitmap(bmp);

This is my code still It is not working

Answer (score 2):

I have used the following solution to solve my problem,and this worked for me.

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(edtext.getDrawingCache());
System.out.println("ashish"+edtext.getText().toString());
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(r, R.drawable.balloon_overlay_focused);
Bitmap bmw=combineImages( bm,bmp);
CompositeImageViewText.setImageBitmap(bmw);
```

//**code for combineimages()**

```
public Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap c, Bitmap s) { // can add a 3rd parameter 'String loc' if you want to save the new image - left some code to do that at the bottom 
        Bitmap cs = null; 

        int width, height = 0; 

        if(c.getWidth() > s.getWidth()) { 
          width = c.getWidth(); 
          height = s.getHeight()+30 ; 
        } else { 
          width = s.getWidth(); 
          height = s.getHeight()+30 ; 
        } 

        cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 

        Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs); 

        comboImage.drawBitmap(c, 0f, 0f, null); 
        comboImage.drawBitmap(s, 0f, 0f, null); 

        // this is an extra bit I added, just incase you want to save the new image somewhere and then return the location 
        /*String tmpImg = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".png"; 

        OutputStream os = null; 
        try { 
          os = new FileOutputStream(loc + tmpImg); 
          cs.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os); 
        } catch(IOException e) { 
          Log.e("combineImages", "problem combining images", e); 
        }*/ 

        return cs; 
      }
```

Hope it helps other !

Answer (score 0):

A "bitmap" is the set of pixels that make up an image.

A "string" is a set of characters that make up a word.

The best you can do is *read* a bitmap, based on the bitmap's *file name*.  That's what Ankit Awasthi illustrated above.

Hopefully that's what you're looking for...